# Remote BLOB Storage and Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sql-server, performance, content-database, remote-blob-storage, rbs

I have a SharePoint Server 2010 documents library. Library's size - 20 Gb. Size increases each year by 1-2 GB. It stores files ranging in size from 1 to 50 MB. Files rarely change.
Should I use the remote blob storage? Will it give a strong boost in performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO, you should definitely use RBS because majority of files are larger than 1MB. In your case, your DB can further grow exceptionally large because of all the binary large object (BLOB) data. And, Reading and writing BLOBs, as well as other relational data, can slow down SQL Server performance because it’s not the ideal place for storing BLOBs. By using RBS to externalize BLOBs stored in the content database, SQL Server and SharePoint Server can jointly manage the data integrity between the database records and the RBS external store on a per-database basis.

http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/C/D/2CDF0F90-DA03-4D71-A395-F69F9CB61453/oit2010-whitepaper-storsimple-sharepoint2010-rbs.pdf

P.S. If BLOB data files are at least 80KB and the DB server I/O is a bottleneck, in other words very small Blobs can also decrease performance.

Comment: Also, to improve the performance in your scenario, you may want to enable BLOB Caching and make sure you plan and design your document management solution appropriately.